# Jenkins - could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Tags: java, ubuntu, github, jenkins, hudson

I'm trying to set up Jenkins / Hudson on my Ubuntu PC. That's not the problem but I set an Android job with the following commands:

```
export CLEAN=false
export LUNCH=cm_ace-userdebug
export REPO_BRANCH=cm-10.1
export RELEASE_TYPE=CM_NIGHTLY
curl -O https://raw.github.com/CyanogenMod/hudson/master/job.sh
. ./job.sh
```

The job stops after a few seconds because of the error:

> could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

How do I fix this error?
Please help!

Comment: Make sure you can reach `https://github.com` on the machine you're having problems with. I'm thinking there's a connectivity issue.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. I tested it by integrating wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com into the job

Comment: @yanniks could you share if you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Jenkins is attempting to open "/dev/tty" or something to ask you for a user name and password.  That is failing because Jenkins is running as a daemon ... and "/dev/tty" can't be used in that context.  The "No such device or address" comes from the failed attempt to open "/dev/tty".

The solution would be to configure the job to use a specific private key for the fetch.  Read the `curl` manual entry and check out the `-E` option.  Alternatively, you could use `-u` and specify the username and password in the `curl` command.